# Getting wrong PDF page on 64-bit iOS device only

Tags: ios, pdf

I have an iOS app that only has a problem on 64 devices. The function where the problem is, is here:

```
- (NSMutableData *)getPage:(NSInteger)pageNumber
{
    NSLog(@"%ld",(long)pageNumber);

    CGPDFDocumentRef SourcePDFDocument = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"full" ofType:@"pdf"]]); // Create the CGPDFDocument from the URL
    if (SourcePDFDocument == NULL) {
        return nil;
    }

    // Reference to Page current Page
    CGPDFPageRef SourcePDFPage = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(SourcePDFDocument, pageNumber);

    CGRect mediaBox = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(SourcePDFPage, kCGPDFMediaBox);
    NSMutableData *outputData = [NSMutableData data];
    CGDataConsumerRef consumer = CGDataConsumerCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFMutableDataRef)outputData);
    CGContextRef context = CGPDFContextCreate(consumer, &mediaBox, NULL);
    // draw
    CGContextBeginPage(context, &mediaBox);
    CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, SourcePDFPage);
    CGContextEndPage(context);
    // cleanup
    CGDataConsumerRelease(consumer);
    CGContextRelease(context);

    return outputData;
}
```

What it does is grab a single paged from a larger pdf and convert it to NSMutableData so that it can be emailed. The problem that it is having on 64-bit devices is that it is grabbing the wrong page (18 pages before). Can anyone see the problem?

Comment: nslog the pagenumber... the code doesn't look bad to me

Comment: ok, the error must be in this function because the page numbers are constant regardless of device

Comment: whats the page number?

Comment: Cast it to size_t explicitly

Comment: the page number is always one more than the desired page. I suppose I could check to see if I'm on a 64-bit device and add 18 to the page number. (not the best solution, but a solution)

Comment: I apologize, what do you mean "Cast it to size_t explicitly"

Comment: I figured it out the "Cast it to size_t explicitly". I did that, then it offset all the pages by 18 (because of the index pages) regardless of devise. So I increase page number by 18 and problem solved, thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an explicit cast to size_t - if you leave that to be implicit there is a difference between 32 and 64 bit

```
// Reference to Page current Page
CGPDFPageRef SourcePDFPage = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(SourcePDFDocument, (size_t)pageNumber);
```