# iOS method retrieves wrong page, sometimes

Tags: ios, pdf

I have an iOS function that grabs a single page from a long PDF and changes it to NSMutableData so that it can be emailed. Here is the function.

```
- (NSMutableData *)getPage:(NSInteger)pageNumber
{
    NSLog(@"%ld",(long)pageNumber);

    CGPDFDocumentRef SourcePDFDocument = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"full" ofType:@"pdf"]]); // Create the CGPDFDocument from the URL
    if (SourcePDFDocument == NULL) {
        return nil;
    }

    // Reference to Page current Page
    CGPDFPageRef SourcePDFPage = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(SourcePDFDocument, pageNumber);

    CGRect mediaBox = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(SourcePDFPage, kCGPDFMediaBox);
    NSMutableData *outputData = [NSMutableData data];
    CGDataConsumerRef consumer = CGDataConsumerCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFMutableDataRef)outputData);
    CGContextRef context = CGPDFContextCreate(consumer, &mediaBox, NULL);
    // draw
    CGContextBeginPage(context, &mediaBox);
    CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, SourcePDFPage);
    CGContextEndPage(context);
    // cleanup
    CGDataConsumerRelease(consumer);
    CGContextRelease(context);

    return outputData;
}
```

The problem is that for any page greater than or equal to 397 of the PDF the method returns the wrong page. When I should get page 397 I get page 399, when I should get page 786 I get page 788. This happens on both 64-bit and 32-bit devices. I know this is a problem with this function because the NSLogged pageNumber is the correct number. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Try with multiple PDFs to make sure there is nothing wrong with the PDF you are using.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting wrong PDF page on 64-bit iOS device only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24855573/getting-wrong-pdf-page-on-64-bit-ios-device-only)

Comment: I believe it is a separate issue from 'Getting wrong PDF page on 64-bit iOS device only'. I believe now that the problem is with the PDF itself not the function.